# How to upgrade React Native the right way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native 0.57.7 and  I want to upgrade to React Native 0.61 using rn-diff-purge but I found that's very painful. Is there a quicker solution?

Comment: Have you read the official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading) about it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this tool](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) from react native community